# lxml iterparse eats up memory for an 4GB XML file, even when clear() is used

Tags: python, xml, lxml, ram, large-files

The purpose of the script is to extract how many articles/books have been published for each year and get this information from  element in the xml file *dblp-2023-10-01.xml*. The file can be found here: https://dblp.org/xml/release/

```
from lxml import etree

xmlfile = 'dblp-2023-10-01.xml'

doc = etree.iterparse(xmlfile, tag='year', load_dtd=True)
_, root = next(doc)
counter_dict = {}
for event, element in doc:
    if element.text not in counter_dict:
        counter_dict[element.text] = 1
    else:
        counter_dict[element.text] += 1
    root.clear()
```

When I run the code for a small file it runs smoothly. What puzzles me is that when I run with the dblp file that it exceeds the 4GB (which is the file size) which doesn't make sense to me.

I tried also to run alternative versions to make sure it clears what it parses like:

```
    for ancestor in elem.xpath('ancestor-or-self::*'):
        while ancestor.getprevious() is not None:
            del ancestor.getparent()[0]
```

Without any improvement

Comment: You need to provide much more debugging information, including the stack trace and some of the output. Does it fail before processing any events? If during, after how many? etc.  Please read [ask].

Comment: Try powershell : $uri = `'https://dblp.org/xml/release/dblp-2023-10-01.xml.gz'`;
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri;
$numbers = $response.Content;
Write-Host $numbers;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** My machine does it in 2,5 minutes locally, so you need the download time too. You should not only clear the `root.clear()`, instead `elem.clear()`:

```
from lxml import etree
import gzip

import psutil
import time
time_start = time.time()

fd = gzip.open('dblp-2023-10-01.xml.gz', "r")

counter_dict = {}
for event, elem in etree.iterparse(fd, events=['end'], recover=True):
    if elem.tag == "year":
        if elem.text not in counter_dict:
            counter_dict[elem.text] = 1
        else:
            counter_dict[elem.text] +=1
    elem.clear()
    
#print(counter_dict)
print(dict(sorted(counter_dict.items())))

print("RAM:")
print(psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / (1024 * 1024))
print("Time:")
print((time.time() - time_start))
```

Output:

```
{'1936': 12, '1937': 16, '1938': 11, '1939': 18, '1940': 10, '1941': 13, '1942': 13, '1943': 8, '1944': 5, '1945': 9, '1946': 31, '1947': 10, '1948': 41, '1949': 52, '1950': 29, '1951': 46, '1952': 114, '1953': 173, '1954': 225, '1955': 213, '1956': 355, '1957': 343, '1958': 464, '1959': 715, '1960': 625, '1961': 903, '1962': 1186, '1963': 1032, '1964': 1108, '1965': 1291, '1966': 1503, '1967': 1763, '1968': 2182, '1969': 2113, '1970': 2227, '1971': 3120, '1972': 3751, '1973': 4414, '1974': 5007, '1975': 5246, '1976': 5695, '1977': 5961, '1978': 6786, '1979': 6913, '1980': 7787, '1981': 8662, '1982': 9939, '1983': 10860, '1984': 12334, '1985': 13890, '1986': 16475, '1987': 17549, '1988': 21633, '1989': 24001, '1990': 28166, '1991': 31084, '1992': 34900, '1993': 40695, '1994': 45290, '1995': 47712, '1996': 52809, '1997': 57099, '1998': 64297, '1999': 71138, '2000': 80955, '2001': 86798, '2002': 97758, '2003': 116385, '2004': 135735, '2005': 158268, '2006': 176458, '2007': 189562, '2008': 203544, '2009': 222653, '2010': 228955, '2011': 250783, '2012': 263294, '2013': 280709, '2014': 292279, '2015': 302656, '2016': 314744, '2017': 339456, '2018': 374688, '2019': 417602, '2020': 433127, '2021': 456839, '2022': 470484, '2023': 305500, '2024': 536}

RAM:
1141.16796875
Time:
151.0215344429016
```

**Option 2 - Download and parse the stream:**

```
import gzip
from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml import etree

import psutil
import time
time_start = time.time()

url = "https://dblp.org/xml/release/"
file = "dblp-2023-10-01.xml.gz"
fd = url+file

f = urlopen(fd)
fz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f, mode="r")

counter_dict = {}
for event, elem in etree.iterparse(fz, events=['end'], recover=True):
    if elem.tag == "year":
        if elem.text not in counter_dict:
            counter_dict[elem.text] = 1
        else:
            counter_dict[elem.text] +=1
    elem.clear()
    
#print(counter_dict)
print(dict(sorted(counter_dict.items())))

print("RAM:")
print(psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / (1024 * 1024))
print("Time:")
print((time.time() - time_start))
```

Output:

```
{'1936': 12, '1937': 16, '1938': 11, '1939': 18, '1940': 10, '1941': 13, '1942': 13, '1943': 8, '1944': 5, '1945': 9, '1946': 31, '1947': 10, '1948': 41, '1949': 52, '1950': 29, '1951': 46, '1952': 114, '1953': 173, '1954': 225, '1955': 213, '1956': 355, '1957': 343, '1958': 464, '1959': 715, '1960': 625, '1961': 903, '1962': 1186, '1963': 1032, '1964': 1108, '1965': 1291, '1966': 1503, '1967': 1763, '1968': 2182, '1969': 2113, '1970': 2227, '1971': 3120, '1972': 3751, '1973': 4414, '1974': 5007, '1975': 5246, '1976': 5695, '1977': 5961, '1978': 6786, '1979': 6913, '1980': 7787, '1981': 8662, '1982': 9939, '1983': 10860, '1984': 12334, '1985': 13890, '1986': 16475, '1987': 17549, '1988': 21633, '1989': 24001, '1990': 28166, '1991': 31084, '1992': 34900, '1993': 40695, '1994': 45290, '1995': 47712, '1996': 52809, '1997': 57099, '1998': 64297, '1999': 71138, '2000': 80955, '2001': 86798, '2002': 97758, '2003': 116385, '2004': 135735, '2005': 158268, '2006': 176458, '2007': 189562, '2008': 203544, '2009': 222653, '2010': 228955, '2011': 250783, '2012': 263294, '2013': 280709, '2014': 292279, '2015': 302656, '2016': 314744, '2017': 339456, '2018': 374688, '2019': 417602, '2020': 433127, '2021': 456839, '2022': 470484, '2023': 305500, '2024': 536}
```

RAM:
1084.80859375
Time:
148.59651041030884

Read also memory efficiency of common data structure, [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/memory-efficiency-of-common-python-data-structures-88f0f720421).

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell why lxml's iterparse needs all that memory but I have tried a simple SAX program

```
import xml.sax

counter_dict = {}

class YearHandler(xml.sax.ContentHandler):

    def __init__(self):
       self.year = ''
       self.isYear = False

    def startElement(self,tag,attributes):
       if tag == 'year':
           self.isYear = True
           self.year = ''

    def endElement(self,tag):
       if self.isYear and tag == 'year':
           self.isYear = False
           yearInt = int(self.year)
           if yearInt in counter_dict:
               counter_dict[yearInt] += 1
           else:
               counter_dict[yearInt] = 1


    def characters(self,content):
        if self.isYear:
           self.year += content

if __name__=='__main__':

    parser=xml.sax.make_parser()

    parser.setFeature(xml.sax.handler.feature_namespaces,0)

    parser.setContentHandler(YearHandler())

    parser.parse('dblp-2023-10-01.xml')

    print(counter_dict)
```

and on my Windows machine it consumes less than 10 MB of memory and outputs

```
{2014: 292279, 2005: 158268, 2011: 250783, 2012: 263294, 2018: 374688, 2008: 203544, 1997: 57099, 2010: 228955, 2016: 314744, 2017: 339456, 2013: 280709, 2002: 97758, 2004: 135735, 2009: 222653, 2007: 189562, 2006: 176458, 1999: 71138, 2015: 302656, 2022: 470484, 2023: 305500, 2019: 417602, 2020: 433127, 1992: 34900, 2021: 456839, 1988: 21633, 1998: 64297, 1986: 16475, 1989: 24001, 1987: 17549, 2001: 86798, 1994: 45290, 1990: 28166, 2003: 116385, 1995: 47712, 2000: 80955, 1993: 40695, 1991: 31084, 1996: 52809, 1954: 225, 1971: 3120, 2024: 536, 1985: 13890, 1984: 12334, 1982: 9939, 1975: 5246, 1983: 10860, 1980: 7787, 1981: 8662, 1964: 1108, 1977: 5961, 1976: 5695, 1972: 3751, 1974: 5007, 1979: 6913, 1973: 4414, 1978: 6786, 1967: 1763, 1965: 1291, 1969: 2113, 1968: 2182, 1970: 2227, 1966: 1503, 1959: 715, 1961: 903, 1953: 173, 1960: 625, 1957: 343, 1955: 213, 1958: 464, 1956: 355, 1951: 46, 1962: 1186, 1952: 114, 1963: 1032, 1946: 31, 1947: 10, 1945: 9, 1939: 18, 1948: 41, 1942: 13, 1949: 52, 1941: 13, 1937: 16, 1940: 10, 1936: 12, 1950: 29, 1943: 8, 1944: 5, 1938: 11}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin! What was the execution time? It took me about 5 minutes with my code, and the memory increased at certain points only, which I still can't figure out what's going on

Comment: It took some minutes, yes, I think on my machine between 4 and 5 minutes, but with a 4 GB input that is expected, I think. I didn't notice some great changes in memory usage during the run, of course the dictionary is being added to, but as I said, in the task manager I couldn't see anything more than 10 MB memory usage. Certainly not anything going anywhere to the size of the input or growing constantly while processing the input.